# Calling different class objects using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to get more grip of Classes and also calling different classes to each other which will be more understandable when showing code before:

**Utils.py**

```py
from proxymanager import ProxyManager # https://pypi.org/project/proxy-manager/

class ProxyServer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.proxy_manager_test = ProxyManager('./test.txt')
        self.proxy_manager_test2 = ProxyManager('./test2.txt')
        self.proxy_manager_test3 = ProxyManager('./test3.txt')
        self.proxy_manager_test4 = ProxyManager('./test4.txt')

    def hello(self):
        return self.proxy_manager_test.random_proxy().get_dict()
    
    def world(self):
        return self.proxy_manager_test2.random_proxy().get_dict()
    
    def hey(self):
        return self.proxy_manager_test3.random_proxy().get_dict()
        
    def yes(self):
        return self.proxy_manager_test4.random_proxy().get_dict()
        
class Testing:
        
    def GetData(self, value=None):
        if value:
           dataSaved = getattr(ProxyServer(), value)() # <--- Technically works but is it correct way to do it?
           print(dataSaved)
```

**Main.py**

```py
import random
import time
from .utils import Testing

scraper = Testing()

randomList = ["hello", "world", "hey", "yes"]

while True:
    response = scraper.GetData(
        value=random.choice(randomList)
    )
    time.sleep(10)
```

My concern is the `dataSaved = getattr(ProxyServer(), value)()` which seem to work as expected but i'm not sure if its correct way to do it, I did get some review about it but the answer I got was that it will technically work but its wrong to do it this way and I want a second opinion from you guys, Is it actually wrong doing it this way?

And please, let me know if I am missing anything else here to provide missing information :)

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*. Consider waiting till a full day has past and posting a follow-up question instead.

Comment: @Mast Woops im sorry! It is my fault, I was not able to find documenation about if it is ok to add additional code in my question (At the very bottom) based from Grajdeanu Alex. answer?

Comment: No, consider asking a follow-up question as stated in my previous comment. Feel free to add a link to both this and the new question to the other one for bonus context. Don't touch the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've over-engineered the code a bit. If I were to write this code I wouldn't have used a class at all. Looking at what your code does I understand that:

- you have multiple proxies files
- you randomly choose one of them and perform whatever actions based on that

Why not just doing something along the following lines:

```
import random
import time

from proxymanager import ProxyManager


PROXY_FILES = (
    './test.txt',
    './test2.txt',
    './test3.txt',
    './test4.txt',
)
DELAY = 10


def get_random_proxy():
    """
    Return a random proxy dict from a random file.
    """
    random_file = random.choice(PROXY_FILES)
    return ProxyManager(random_file).random_proxy().get_dict()


def main():
    while True:
        proxy = get_random_proxy()
        print(f'Do something with {proxy["http"]}\n')
        time.sleep(DELAY)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This approach will save you a lot of development time since you:

- won't have to add a new method to your `ProxyServer` each time you have a new proxy file.
- won't have to keep track of `random_list` (which is not quite random since it has to match the attributes of the class)
- you won't need a `Testing()` class anymore

Notice that with this version is really easy to figure out what you're doing.

### Recommendations ([PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)):

- use appropriate naming for your variables (*snake_case* naming convention for methods/functions, *UPPER_CASE* naming convention for constants);
- use docstrings to help your readers understand the code;

---

If you're really tied to use classes, I'd mix your solution with mine and do something along these lines:

```
import random
import time

import requests

from proxymanager import ProxyManager


PROXY_FILES = (
    './test.txt',
    './test2.txt',
    './test3.txt',
    './test4.txt',
)
DELAY = 10


class ProxyServer:
    def __init__(self, random_proxy_file):
        self.proxy_manager = ProxyManager(random_proxy_file)

    def get_proxy(self):
        """
        Return a random proxy dict.
        """
        return self.proxy_manager.random_proxy().get_dict()


class Scrapper:
    def __init__(self, base_url):
        self.base_url = base_url

    @staticmethod
    def _get_random_proxy():
        random_proxy_file = random.choice(PROXY_FILES)
        return ProxyServer(random_proxy_file).get_proxy()

    def get_url_data(self):
        proxy = self._get_random_proxy()
        data = requests.get(self.base_url, proxies={'http': proxy['http']})
        return data

    def do_something_with_data(self, data):
        return data


def main():
    scrapper = Scrapper('http://scrapeme.not/')
    
    while True:
        data = scrapper.get_url_data()
        scrapper.do_something_with_data(data)
        time.sleep(DELAY)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But notice how this has become a lot more complex than it should've been. Some advantages that this has over your solution:

- it uses better naming;
- it avoids creating multiple `ProxyManager()` instances;
- it avoids mapping the `getattr()` to a value from a list you'd have to maintain all the time as complexity of the scrapper increases;

---

And to answer your question: no, it's not wrong to use `getattr()` like that but in this specific case I don't think it's necessary due to the above listed reasons.

Comment: Hello!  This is very good review and I do really like it! There is so much I can easily improve with this code review and I do apprecaite it! There is one missing part that I might have needed to more explain, the reason why I had different functions for proxies is that my plan later on is that when I want to call a specific proxy, in my case etc: proxy "world" then I want to specific use the `./test2.txt` and in our case you are using a random function. For now I had a random `randomList = ["hello", "world", "hey", "yes"]` for this part but later on I will instead call a specific one.

Comment: And here I might need in your case maybe a small change if it doesn't take up too much time for you! But the choice of calling a specific proxy is much needed and I would like to call the specific proxy when I do it later on.

Comment: Would you be able to put PROXY_FILES into a dict and then you can just do something like: `PROXY_FILES [proxyType].random_proxy().get_dict()` where proxyType can be etc: `hello` ?